# Optimized way to find values with top 20 frequencies in spark dataframe

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have a spark dataframe. We are trying to find the values with top 20 frequencies in a column.
Ex) [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4]

In the above list,
1 is occuring 3 times
2 is occuring 2 times
4 is occuring 1 time

We are trying to find this using pandas.

And then creating UDF in spark and using it there.
This works for smaller datasets, but when the datasets are too tall (20M rows), we are facing memory issues sometimes.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("unit_testing_spark").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")


def find_freq_values(col_list):
    if len(col_list) == 0:
        return []

    df = pd.DataFrame(col_list, columns=["value"])
    df = df[['value']].groupby(['value'])['value'] \
        .count() \
        .reset_index(name='count') \
        .sort_values(['count'], ascending=False) \
        .head(20)
    res = df.to_dict(orient='records')

    for curr_data in res:
        curr_value = curr_data["value"]
        ldt = str(type(curr_value)).lower()
        if "time" in ldt or "date" in ldt:
            curr_data["value"] = str(curr_value)

    return res

s = find_freq_values([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4])
print(s)
# Output: [{'value': 1, 'count': 3}, {'value': 2, 'count': 2}, {'value': 4, 'count': 1}]

column_data = ["col_1"]
column_header = tuple(column_data)

data = [[1], [1], [1], [2], [2], [4]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, column_header)

find_freq_udf = F.udf(find_freq_values, ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType(), True)))

freq_res_df = df.select(*[find_freq_udf(F.collect_list(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
freq_res = freq_res_df.collect()[0].asDict()
print(freq_res)
# Output: {'col_1': [{'count': '3', 'value': '1'}, {'count': '2', 'value': '2'}, {'count': '1', 'value': '4'}]}
```

Error message:
"An error occurred while calling o514.collectToPython.\n: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 66.0 failed 10 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.9 in stage 66.0 (TID 379) (w382f6d7a114442a8bd741d53661a2c3b-srpz3ldim3sr2-w-1.c.projectid.internal executor 10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container from a bad node: container_1658234225716_0001_01_000011 on host: w382f6d7a114442a8bd741d53661a2c3b-srpz3ldim3sr2-w-1.c.projectid.internal. Exit status: 143.

To perform multiple columns parallely we are using the following statement.

How can this be optimized to avoid memory issue?

Answer (score 3):

One way would be only use spark for computing the frequencies. here is one way to do it.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, col

x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4] # input data

df = sc.parallelize(x).toDF(['ID'])
df = df.groupBy('ID')
df = df.agg(count('ID').alias('id_count'))
df = df.orderBy(col('id_count').asc())
df = df.limit(20)

df.show()
```